# How to compare date difference in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm appending a column to my pandas dataframe which is the time difference between two dates.

```
df['time_diff'] = datetime.dt(2018,1,1) - df['IN_TIME']
```

the type if the new column in `<m8[ns]`. I'm trying to filter the rows whose 'time_diff' is greater than 30 days but I can't compare `<m8[ns]` with a number. How can I do this comparison?

Comment: Take the datetime difference as an object and that object will have a days int property.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way. Note you don't need to use the `datetime` module for these calculations as Pandas has some intuitive functionality for these operations.

```
df['time_diff'] = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01') - df['IN_TIME']

df = df[df['time_diff'].dt.days > 30]
```

This solution assumes `df['IN_TIME']` is a `datetime` series; if it is not, you can convert via `df['IN_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['IN_TIME'])`.